# What do you call a situation when the traffic is stopped on the part of the road which is being maintained?

Tags: meaning

It is not a gridlock or deadlock and vehicles do not wait in queues, but it is a situation when you know traffic is ..... because of the road rehabilitation.

Comment: Traffic has been diverted because  of the work in process. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/divert

Comment: If you start a question with "how do you call" it is a sure indication that you are not a native speaker. You should consider whether your question is appropriate to English Language Learners.

Comment: Traffic is at a standstill. (USA)

Answer (score 2):

The usual phrase, at least in the NYC metro area, is ***backed up***: "Traffic on the FDR Drive is ***backed up*** from the RFK/Triboro Bridge to 14th Street due to road construction at 130th Street."

If the condition obtains in a non-continuous fashion at several locations on the same road, you may also hear the term ***congested*** or ***congestion***: "There is an accident at Exit 12 on the Hutchinson Parkway, *backing* traffic *up* down to Boston Road, but you'll also see ***congestion*** right back to the Whitestone Bridge."

If by "traffic is stopped", you mean that no vehicles are permitted on a section of roadway (the segment is closed), then ***diverted*** is appropriate: "Traffic is being ***diverted*** from the West Side Highway at 96th Street due to sinkhole repair at 91st Street."

Answer (score 0):

I think you are thinking of a 'traffic bottleneck'.

A traffic bottleneck occurs when you have a physical object blocking part of the road, causing disruption. Unlike a traffic jam, where there is no obstruction, and driving is just slow.

A bottleneck can refer to construction, or a car wreck, or some other physical thing blocking a lane and causing cars to merge, and slow.

Sources (Don't hate me because its a wiki o3o )

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_bottleneck